# Compute differences between Point2D<UCS> and Point2D<GCS>

Tags: c++, generics, geometry, typechecking

[**This is related to the a thread that was posted earlier in this forum.**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1046248/what-are-some-recommended-frameworks-for-manipulating-spatial-data-in-c/4090695)

[What are some recommended frameworks for manipulating spatial data in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1046248/what-are-some-recommended-frameworks-for-manipulating-spatial-data-in-c/4090695)

Do you know of a geometry library that offer generics-based compile-time protection from mixing UCS and GCS coordinates? For example, I'm looking for something that allows me to write code like this:

```
Point2D<GCS> p1( 1.0, 1.0 );
Point2D<UCS> p2( 1.0, 1.0 );
std::cout << (p1 - p2) << std::endl; // compile-time error: mixing types!
```

I don't need protection from mixing different UCS's, only mixing GCS and a UCS. Mixing local and global coordinate systems is a completely avoidable error that can be eliminated with proper book-keeping, which should be simplified using C++'s strong type-checking and support of generics. I'd rather use an existing library than re-invent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function to convert UCS to GCS. Then you can perform `std::cout<<(p1-p2)<<"\n;` when both of them are in GCS.

Then, there will will be no compiler error due to mixing types.